# How to Display only products in shopify search results?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, shopify

I want to display only products from Shopify products but there are showing also pages and posts here is my code for search result:

```
<div class="product-list">
    {% if grid_results == false %}
    {% for item in search.results %}
    {% include 'search-result' %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <div class="grid-uniform">
      {% for item in search.results %}
      {% include 'search-result-grid' %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
```

Now I got the following code:

```
{% if item.object_type == 'product' %}
```

But where to put this code so I can get only products for search any text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shopify has excellent self help guides for most of the stuff. Here's one such

[Show only products in storefront search results](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/navigation/show-only-products-in-search-results)

Comment: Do realize if in page 2 of the search results, if you use code to filter it out, there's a chance of the page showing 0 results. Having said that put the code `{% if item.object_type == 'product' %}` above the two `include` statements.